# how to make a chatbot start conversation initially

Tags: python, machine-learning, chatbot

I created a chatbot to be used in a webpage using conversional type. Now without user texting the bot, wanted the bot to start the chat saying something upon accessing the webpage.
I googled for the resources and found all are building sites only...Am in searching of a coding path to get this thing done.
Like, I need to develop the chatbot to start the conversion itself by displaying some options-buttons to proceed in programmatical approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I could able to build rule based bot but need to build like button based chatbot with autorun at website start